# Why is $\binom{n}{f}^g=O(n^{fg})$ true?

Tags: asymptotics

Why is it true? I understand why $n^g$ but how does the $f$ get there in the power??
I believe from the context that it's not just that $\binom{n}{f}^g$ is strictly smaller than $n^{f g}$, but rather that it really belongs to this class, which means it's also tightly bounded by it or very close. But why is it?

Answer (score 3):

This reduces to showing $\binom{n}{f} = O(n^f)$.

In one variable the idea of an approximation being tight is pretty simple; you just see if the limit of the quotient goes to one.

In multiple variables there's no such thing as "the" limit.  There are limits along different curves.  Some may be tight and some may not be, but as long as the limit along one curve is tight there's no way of improving things across the board.

In situation at hand we have $$\binom{n}{f} = \frac{1}{f!}n(n-1)\ldots(n-f+1)$$.  For f small compared to n, the $(n-i) \approx n$.  If n grows a lot faster than k!, then it also blows out the k! term in the denominator as well.  So along a curve like this the bound is tight.

(It's also possible we're considering fixed k and just considering the growth as a function of n, in which case the $1/k!$ is just a constant factor.)

Comment: So it's tight? ....

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "tight" when you have more than one variable?

Comment: That they are equivalent and that the left side isn't strictly smaller in class. Let's put it another way, could you bound the right side by a big O of the left one?

Comment: If you view k as a constant, you have $n^k = O(\binom{n}{k})$.  If you view this as an expression in two variables then this does not hold.  That said, you're unlikely to find a useful function that's equivalent in this sense to $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{n}{f} = \frac{n!}{f!\,(n-f)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-f+1)}{f!} \leq \frac{n^f}{f!}\leq n^f\,,$$
and you can raise the whole thing to the power of $g$.

Comment: Ok . This is obvious but is ittight? How do you get away with factoring out a whole 1/f! ?

Comment: We're taking big-$O$ with respect to $n$ and treating $f$ as a constant.

Comment: In the context f isn't a constant but a variable. Please explain why you can treat it as such. And you say it's a big O, that means it's not tight?

Comment: @bilanush Big-O is about what happens when some variable goes to infinity, so you have to pick which variable you're sending to infinity for that. Big-O also doesn't have to be tight.

Comment: @bilanush Big-O means big-O, just like $\leq$ means $\leq$. Using it doesn't indicate that it is or isn't tight.

Comment: I know. I said from the context it should either be tight or close. Because my book is interested in showing that the complexity is high and there is no point in giving a bound larger because it doesn't prove the algorithm is difficult

Comment: @bilanush OK -- it sounded like you were suggesting that, because it's big-$O$, it's not tight. For constant $f$, it is tight since, for large enough $n$, $n(n-1)\cdots(n-f+1)\geq (n/2)^f$.

Comment: @bilanush: "Tight along a single curve" is enough to prove that the complexity is high, because that represents a particular situation the algorithm has to handle.